# add method linked lists

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I have created a linked list with objects. The object is called Student and has three parameters: name, age, grade. Here are my classes.

**Link**

```
class Link {
    public Object s;
    public Link next;

    public Link(Object Student) {
        s=Student;
        next=null;
    }
}
```

**Student**

```
class Student {
    private static String name;
    private static int age;
    private static int grade;

    public Student (String n, int a, int g) {
        setName(n);
        setGrade(g);
        setAge(a);
    }

    public static void setName(String n) {
        name=n;
    }

    public static void setGrade(int g) {
        grade=g;
    }

    public static void setAge(int a) {
        age=a;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade; 
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " +name+ " Age: " +age+ " Grade: " +grade; 
    }
}
```

**List**

```
import java.util.*;
class List {
    private static LinkedList<Student> ll = new LinkedList<Student>();
    private static Link first;
    public List() {
        first=null;
    }

    public static void addStudent() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the student's name;");
        String n = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the student's age;");
        int b = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the student's grade;");
        int g = s.nextInt();
        Student nStudent = new Student(n, b, g);
        Link newStudent = new Link(nStudent);
        newStudent.next=first;
        first=newStudent;
        ll.add(nStudent);
    }

    public static Link findStudent() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the student's name?");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        Link current = first;
        String name = Student.getName();
        while (name!= n) {
            if (current.next==null)
                return null;
            else
                current=current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public static void change () {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Link h = findStudent();
        System.out.println("If you want to change his name press 1;");
        System.out.println("If you want to change his age press 2;");
        System.out.println("If you want to change his grade press 3;");
        int l = sc.nextInt();
        if (l==1) {
            System.out.println("What name do you want the student to have?");
            String newname = sc.nextLine();
            Student.setName(newname);

        } else if (l==2) {
            System.out.println("What age do you want the student to have?");
            int j = sc.nextInt();
            Student.setAge(j);
        }
        else if (l==3) {
            System.out.println("What grade do you want the student to have?");
            int e = sc.nextInt();
            Student.setGrade(e);
        }
    }

    public static void show() {
        System.out.println(ll);
    }
}
```

**Course**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Course {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int v = sc.nextInt();
        if (v==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (v==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (v==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        if (a==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (a==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (a==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        if (r==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (r==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (r==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        if (c==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (c==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (c==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int d = sc.nextInt();
        if (d==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (d==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (d==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        if (x==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (x==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (x==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int h = sc.nextInt();
        if (h==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (h==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (h==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int p = sc.nextInt();
        if (p==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (p==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (p==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        if (m==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (m==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (m==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        if (y==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (y==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (y==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int q = sc.nextInt();
        if (q==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (q==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (q==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int w = sc.nextInt();
        if (w==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (w==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (w==3) {
            List.show();
        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("To add a student press 1");
        System.out.println("To change something press 2");
        System.out.println("To see your students press 3");
        int f = sc.nextInt();
        if (f==1) {
            List.addStudent();
        }else if (f==2) {
            List.change();
        }else if (f==3) {
            List.show();
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that in the Course class, I have written the same code multiple times but that is because I could not find a way with which after I execute a command, I would get back to the main menu and the content of the list would not be lost.
Apparently, my add method is wrong and when I execute the program the output is this:

**Output**

```
What do you want to do?
To add a student press 1
To change something press 2
To see your students press 3
1
What is the student's name;
Tom
What is the student's age;
16
What is the student's grade;
90
What do you want to do?
To add a student press 1
To change something press 2
To see your students press 3
1
What is the student's name;
Eric
What is the student's age;
16
What is the student's grade;
91
What do you want to do?
To add a student press 1
To change something press 2
To see your students press 3
3
[Name: Eric Age: 16 Grade: 91, Name: Eric Age: 16 Grade: 91]
What do you want to do?
To add a student press 1
To change something press 2
To see your students press 3
```

Why when I add a Student in the class, it duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem, is that your Student.class is static.

```
private static String name;
private static int age;
private static int grade;
```

This part tells java, that you only need one variable/Class. So your Linked list just stores 2 reference to the same static fields.

You need to remove your static keyword.

Comment: But if I remove the static reference, I will have other multiple errors

Comment: Don't worry, the IDE is helping you along the way. You have to remove the static qualifiers from the setter/getter functions aswell.
for e.g.: public static void setGrade 
It's important, that you grasp what static really means, take your time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using static fields in your Student class.

```
private static String name;
private static int age;
private static int grade;
```

Static fields don't belong to an instance but belong to the class per se.
It doesn't matter how many Student instances you create (using the `new` keyword), the value for the `static` fields will be shared between them.

You have to remove the `static` keyword in the Student class.
Please refer to the official documentation: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: But If I remove the static references, I have errors such as:                  **non-static method can be referenced to static content**

Comment: You have to remove the static keyword from the getters and setters.
That is because you can't access a non-static field from a static method.

If you are interested in know more about the static keyword you can refer to this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

All of the problems result from the decision to use `static` variables in your `Student` class.  This means that there is only one copy of each of those variables for the entire class, no matter how many `Student` objects you create.

Make them non-`static`.  This means you'll have to remove `static` off your getters and setters in the `Student` class.

In your `List` class, you access the getters from a static context, e.g. `Student.getName()`.  You will need to get the object stored in the `Link` and cast it to a `Student`.  Then you will be able to call `getName()` on it.

As an aside, the `Link` class should be a generic class, e.g. `class Link<T>`, so that when you use it in your `List` class, you can use it as `Link<Student>`, so you don't have to cast it when referring to the `Object` it holds (it would hold a `T`).

In `change`, you will need to do something similar -- regarding the `Student` referred found by `findStudent`, call your setters on that student object, instead of calling it in a static context.

Additionally, in `findStudent`, [use `equals` to compare `String` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), not `!=` or `==`.

Comment: How to fix the bug in the change method?